# Values are set as null inside the database when the respective values are not passed while updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update the some keys and values inside the database. I already have some fields filled like `firstname`, `lastname` and now I want to update those documents with profile picture, contact number etc.

When I pass those values using `update` then the fields which are already set up become null, i.e `firstname` and `lastname` become null. I want `firstname` and `lastname` set as before if the user doesn't want to update those values and update only the later values inside the document.

If the user wants to update both `firstname`  and `lastname` as well as profile photo, then I want those be updated too.

I have used the update method of mongo and request for the new value for updating. I passed the new values through postman but do not pass the old values which were already in the database. When updated, it shows null for those whose values.

```
router.put('/:id/edit',upload.array("images",2),function(req,res,next){
    shopid= req.params.id,
    console.log(req.body);

     User.find({"_id":shopid}).update({
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname: req.body.lastname,
            contact_no : req.body.contact_no,
            images:{
                shop_logo:req.files[0].path,
                shop_picture: req.files[1].path,
             },
            shopname:req.body.shopname,
            updated_at: Date.now(),
    },function(err,data){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }else{
            res.json(data);
         }
    });

});
```

The result:

```
_id: "5ce29ba3e0c2d825d9e5a39f"
firstname: null
lastname: "Gyaawali"
geo: Array
shopkeeper: true
created_at: 2019-05-20T12:20:51.407+00:00
updated_at: 2019-05-23T15:00:04.442+00:00
__v: 0
contact_no: 9837949483
pan_no:"55343fASDE"
images: Object
shop_logo: "public/shop_logo/images-1558623604437-flag-map-of-nepal-logo-C43E9EAFA..."
shop_picture: "public/shop_logo/images-1558623604439-flat-sale-background_23-21477500..."
shopname: "Hello.shop"
```

I dont expect the `firstname` field to be changed. But it is changed to null.

Answer (score 3):

Because doing that query: you are updating also those fields. Even you don't send any value to them, you are updating those fields with **null** (for example **req.body.firstname** is null because the firstname is not into the post body). If you don't want to update them, you should not include those fields to the query.
If you don't want to update **firstname** and **lastname** but the other fields yes, the query should be something like this:

```
User.find({"_id":shopid}).update({
        contact_no : req.body.contact_no,
        images:{
            shop_logo:req.files[0].path,
            shop_picture: req.files[1].path,
         },
        shopname:req.body.shopname,
        updated_at: Date.now(),
},function(err,data){
    if(err){
        res.json(err);
    }else{
        res.json(data);
     }
});
```

Hope this answer your question!

Comment: I also want  to update the values for firstname and lastname if the user wants to update them. If they don't want to update those fields then I don't want those field's value to be null in the database. I want to be as is it before.

Answer (score 2):

Just pre-check the keys if it exists in req.body then only update it. Like this below :

```js
router.put("/:id/edit", upload.array("images", 2), function (req, res, next) {
    let shopid = req.params.id;
    let {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        contact_no,
        shopname
    } = req.body;
    let updateObj = {};
    firstname && (updateObj.firstname = firstname);
    lastname && (updateObj.lastname = lastname);
    contact_no && (updateObj.contact_no = contact_no);
    shopname && (updateObj.shopname = shopname);
    updateObj.updated_at = Date.now();
    updateObj.images = {
        shop_logo: req.files[0].path,
        shop_picture: req.files[1].path
    };
    User.find({
        _id: shopid
    }).update(
        updateObj,
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(data);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer.